# C++ Do i need to define header guards for nested classes?

Tags: c++, header, include-guards

Please see the given example:

```
#ifndef OUTER_H
#define OUTER_H

class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        Innner();
    };

};

#endif
```

My question is: **Do I need to create a header guard somewhere for my Inner class, or just one for the whole file?**

Comment: Header guards are for the whole header file, not individual classes.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your main header guard contains everything, and I'm assuming that is a **.h** file, which means it contains only declarations (or at least it should), then everything that is within the guard is guarded. So in short, no, you don't need an extra guard.